# how to reload top most window from iframe?

Tags: facebook, browser, iframe, reload

I'm developing a facebook app which has the following "structure":

```
Browser window (facebook.com/page/xxxx)
  -- My app's iframe
    -- Like button's iframe
```

I'm using a Like button within my app so that's an iframe inside an iframe, when the users clicks on the like button I'd like to show the content so the page currently looks somethin like this:

```
if ( is_fan() ) {
    //show content
} else {
    //show like button plus other text
}
```

The actual logic to check if the user is already a fan is working as intended, the problem is that when I click the like button I need the whole page to reload in order to show the "fan content", if I do this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    top.location.reload();
});
```

The page seems to reload but everything stays the same, but if I click "Like" and the click the refresh button in my browser everything shows up just fine.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We reference the facebook parent page as `top`.

use `top.location.href="";` or `top.location.reload();`

Comment: Hi, for some reason is doesn't work, I'm updating the question with details.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will ask user whether he wants to resubmit the form.

Comment: that is if you are using .reload(). Facebook posts signed_requests to the iframe using a form. therefore if the iframe reloads, the POST_DATA get sent again and asks for confirmation. If you use .href="YOUR_URL"; you wont see this

Answer (score 2):

Neither `top.location.href="";` or `top.location.reload();` worked for me.

I had to use `top.location.href="http://www.facebook.com/appurl";`

Answer (score 2):

Try `top.location.reload(true);` instead of `top.location.reload();`

Extracted from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp:

> By default, the location.reload() method reloads from the cache, but
>   by you can force the the reload to get the page from server by setting
>   the forceGet parameter to true: location.reload(true).

Answer (score 0):

To reload you could use `top.location.href = top.location.href;`